# speed up write to texbox in wpf with scroll to end?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, textbox, event-handling

I have been looking a long time for a way to update a multi lined textbox as fast as possible in C#/WPF. So I thought I would check with you guys and see if you could give me some pointers/hints or help.

What I want is to be able to output as much data as fast as possible to a multi lined textbox with scroll to end on update, the data is coming from a serial connection. I have done this in C#/Forms without any problems. But in WPF it's not that easy.

So if I only write to a textbox with one line, then it takes 940ms for 5000 items.
But for multi line it takes 143 seconds.
And if I do not scroll to the end of the textbox, then it takes 112 seconds for the same data.

The code creates a class instance with a queue, fills the queue with 5000 items, and then trying to output the data to the UI->texbox as fast as it can.
I add stopwatch tick to the output so I can see the timing for each function.

Displayed Output format

ItemValue **DQ->** added to queue tick from start **Ev->** dequeued event tick from start **TB->** textbox output time(ms) from start,

[Picture of the program](http://lizerd.se/images/FIFOe.PNG)

I put together a small test program, code below is the same as the project that can be downloaded here -> [Link to project](http://lizerd.se/images/BlockingCollectionAsFIFO.rar)

The testcase if statements are in MainWindow:TxTextAdd()

My thought was that there would be a way to change the event handling so it could output as many items as possible for each time the ui/event handler fires. So we could print multiple items at once instead of one each event ?
But I do not have any idea how to implement that solution.

Any ideas ?

```
enter 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace BlockingCollectionAsFIFO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        /// Create FIFO class
        FIFO_Class FIFOqueue = new FIFO_Class();

        // Display stopwatch
        Stopwatch DispStop = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        // Holds texbox string in one of the tests
        string TextBox_Text = "";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // register UI update event to populate textbox from queue dequeue
            FIFOqueue.UI_Update += new FIFO_Class.UI_EventHandler(TxTextAdd);

            string ID = "A";

            /// Create new add thread in class
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if(i == 1)
                {
                    ID = "B";
                }
                else if(i == 2)
                {
                    ID = "C";
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {
                    ID = "D";
                }
                else if (i == 4)
                {
                    ID = "E";
                }
                // create thread
                FIFOqueue.CreateAddThread(ID);
            }

            /// Create new read thread in class
            FIFOqueue.CreateReadThread();
        }

        public void TxTextAdd(string Data)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    /// Put togheter the string that we are going to display
                    Data += " TB->" + DispStop.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms";

                    /// true => only update the one row texbox with the latest string
                    if(true)
                    {
                        textbox2.Text = Data;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /// true => add string to TextBox_Text variable and display that (scroll to end)
                        /// false => add string to TextBox control and scroll to end
                        if (true)
                        {
                            TextBox_Text += Data + System.Environment.NewLine;
                            textbox.Text = TextBox_Text;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            textbox.Text += Data + System.Environment.NewLine;
                            textbox.ScrollToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {}
            }));

        }

        private void btn_RUN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            /// Dispose alive dequeue thread
            FIFOqueue.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class FIFO_Class
    {
        // Main Queue
        private BlockingCollection<Package> queue = new BlockingCollection<Package>(new ConcurrentQueue<Package>());

        // Events
        public delegate void UI_EventHandler(string message);
        public event UI_EventHandler UI_Update;

        private Thread DeQueueThread;

        Stopwatch stop = Stopwatch.StartNew();


        public void CreateAddThread(string ID)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => Add(ID));
            t.Start();
        }


        private void Add(string ID)
        {
            /// Just add some data
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Package pack = new Package();
                pack.ID = ID;
                pack.Data = i;
                /// Add pack into queue
                queue.Add(pack);
            }
        }

        public void CreateReadThread()
        {
            DeQueueThread = new Thread(ProcessPackets);
            DeQueueThread.Start();
        }

        private void ProcessPackets()
        {
            string Output;

            /// the try function exist so I can use abort thread
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    /// Retrive a package from queue
                    Package e = queue.Take();
                    // check if there is any data in package
                    if (e != null)
                    {
                        /// Convert data from package to string, stopwatch puts number of ticks from the time the thread was created
                        Output = e.ID + e.Data.ToString() + " DQ-> " + stop.ElapsedTicks.ToString() + " ticks";
                        /// check if we have any subscribers on UIupdate event
                        UI_Update_Process(Output);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
            }

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Abort Thread.
            DeQueueThread.Abort();
            // Wait for the thread to terminate.
            DeQueueThread.Join();
        }

        // UI update Handler Event process
        protected void UI_Update_Process(string Data)
        {
            if (UI_Update != null)
            {
                //UI_Update(Data);
                UI_Update(Data + " Ev->" + stop.ElapsedTicks.ToString() + "ticks");
            }
        }
    }

    class Package
    {
        public string ID;
        public int Data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need all the lines in the textbox? If not, you could virtualize the text buffer and only show what fits the visual part of the textbox and the scrollbars' position.

Comment: This is for a serial logg, so I would like to be able to keep the data. but sure that is a good idea if the amount of text exceeds a value a can go into (display last 500 lines) mode. 
But still 500 lines takes time to display.

Comment: Have you considered using FlowDocument or AvalonEdit instead? They may be better optimized for this.

Comment: Ha, Tim you are right, did not think flowDocument would have better performence then textblock, no idea compared to textbox. will try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a log:

1. Store/save the log in a file.
2. Put a scrollbar next to the textbox and set its maximum to the number of lines in the log
3. Every time the scrollbar changes get the correct lines from the log that will be visible (no more than that) in the textbox.
4. Every time the log grows change the maximum of the scrollbar.

   - This way you virtualize as much as possible making the textbox fast
   - You can put a buffer between the textbox/scrollbar and the log file to reduce the number of read operations on the log.
   - You don't need to add 500 lines to the textbox; most textboxes do not show that many lines at once.